# SQL - Group By Distinct

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, sql-server-2012

```
   row | P_NO | B_NAME
     1 | 123  | ABC ELEC
     2 | 123  | ABC ELEC
     3 | 123  | ABC ELEC
     4 | 123  | ABC TRANSPORT
     5 | 123  | ABC CONTRACTORS
     6 | 124  | ABC STATIONARY
     7 | 125  | ABC ELEC
     8 | 126  | ABC ELEC
```

I'm very new in SQL. 
How can I select only the P_NO and B_NAME where one P_NO appears for more than one B_NAME.

Output should be only one of the first three rows and row 4 and 5

SQL SERVER 2012

Comment: What is your expected output? I mean how you want to determine which B_Name to be selected?

Comment: Output should be one of the first three rows and row 4 and 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[updated]

what you are looking for is this:

```
select p_no
     , b_name
  from Uhura.dbo.test
 where p_no in (select p_no
                  from Uhura.dbo.test
                 group by
                       p_no
                having count(distinct b_name) > 1)
 group by
       p_no
     , b_name
```

it counts the number of distinct b_name for each p_no and uses the ones that have more than one as a filter for the outer select. it then eliminates the duplicates by grouping:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

try this ...

```
SELECT 
  P_NO,
  B_NAME 
FROM
  table_name1 
WHERE P_NO IN 
  (SELECT 
    P_NO 
  FROM
    table_name1 
  GROUP BY P_NO 
  HAVING COUNT(P_NO) > 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.P_NO,a.B_NAME 
FROM tab1 a
INNER JOIN 
  (SELECT P_NO,B_NAME
   FROM tab1 
   GROUP BY P_NO,B_NAME
   HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) b ON a.P_NO = b.P_NO
```

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d9332f/8)</kbd>

This JOINS your original table with a SELECT that gives you only the P_NO's that occurr more than once.

Comment: @user2955297. i edited my answer. see if it is what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
;with TempData as (Select row ,P_NO,DataCount =ROW_NUMBER()
                    over(PARTITION By P_NO Order By B_NAME)
                    from YourTable )


Select * 
from YourTable
where P_NO In (Select distinct P_NO from TempData where DataCount>1)
```

or

```
Select distinct T.* 
From YourTable T
    Inner Join TempData TD on T.P_NO=TD.P_NO
Where TD.DataCount>1
```

Comment: @user2955297: Updated the answer!! try now please